# Generated image in iOS app looks different from original vector image

Tags: ios, vector, uiimage, xcode6

I added a PDF vector file in xcode image assets. The vector file has color and designs. However, when it is generated on the simulator, the shape retains, but the color and the design is all gone, replaced w a flat color.

```
// code to add the button
- (void) addReplyButton:(STRContent *)content {
    UIButton *replyBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    replyBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [[replyBtn imageView] setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [replyBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reply_button"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.photoView addSubview:replyBtn];
}
```

The original image

[image: the image]

The output

[image: the output]

Comment: does it happens every time? or sometimes showing correct image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem - i was doing UIButtonTypeRoundedRect, where UIBottomtypeCustom worked.

```
UIButton *replyBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue before, and in my case, there are two files have same filename.

In this case, it is showing image by random selection among same names